# JavaScript: how to remove line that contain specific string

Tags: javascript, replace

How can I remove a complete line if it contains a specific string like the following?

```
#RemoveMe
```

Comment: Remove from what?  Are you talking about having a long multiline string in a variable, and replacing part of it?  Are you talking about removing a line of HTML from the DOM?  Or what?

Answer (score 44):

If you have a multi-line string, you could use a RegExp with the `m` flag:

```
var str = 'line1\n'+
'line2\n'+
'#RemoveMe line3\n'+
'line4';

str.replace(/^.*#RemoveMe.*$/mg, "");
```

The `m` flag will treat the `^` and `$` meta characters as the beginning and end of each line, not the beginning or end of the whole string.

Comment: This is great! Works perfectly for displaying post summaries when they're written in Markdown and you don't want to show the headings.

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by @CMS , it simply replaces the line with "", still there is an extra line.

For String:

```
var str = 'line1\n'+
'line2\n'+
'#RemoveMe line3\n'+
'line4';
```

If you want the output like this :

```
line1
line2
line4
```

instead of

```
line1
line2

line4
```

Try this :

```
str.split('\n').filter(function(line){ 
    return line.indexOf( "#RemoveMe" ) == -1;
  }).join('\n')
```

All the lines containing the string '#RemoveMe' are simply filtered out, also multiple keywords can be used during filtering.