# How to remove complete line from the string on basis of string match using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this string

```
const str = "fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String func2(Window: String): String function3(param: String): String"
```

I have removed the `Window: String` from `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String` by using the regular expression.

`str.replace(/(, )?Window: String/g, '')`

Now I want to remove the complete line if there is one argument and whose value is `Window: String`

It should give

```
fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String
function3(param: String): String
```

Comment: May be it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930852/javascript-how-to-remove-line-that-contain-specific-string

Comment: You say you have removed `Window: String` but it is still in your expected result?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following approach (in case if all the lines are separated by a newline, i.e. each line is on separate line):

```js
const str = `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String
func2(Window: String): String
function3(param: String): String`;
const regex = /^[^\s(]+\(Window:\s*String\): .+\n*/gm;
const result = str.replace(regex, '');

console.log(result);
```

---

For single-line text use the following approach:

```js
const str = `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String func2(Window: String): String function3(param: String): String`;
const regex = /[^\s(]+\(Window:\s*String\): [^(\s]+\s*/gm;
const result = str.replace(regex, '');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/5umsofb1/ and it is giving `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String func2(Window: String): String function3(param: String): String`

Comment: Yes. I have this string `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String func2(Window: String): String function3(param: String): String` and you have `fnct1(param: Int, Window: String): String
func2(Window: String): String 
function3(param: String): String` enter line at the end

Comment: @Williams, see my notation in 1st sentence. You should have mentioned that moment

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I need to update one more thing. I took hardcode String of `Window`. It could be anything. How can we make it ? Suppose `const str = `fnct1(param: Int, Window: Int): String func2(Window: String): String function3(param: String): String`;` it should return `fnct1(param: Int): String function3(param: String): String`

Comment: @Williams, this `[^\s(]+\(Window:\s*String\): [^(\s]+\s*|(, )?Window:\s*[A-Z][^)]+` should do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157554/discussion-between-williams-and-romanperekhrest).